# How do I populate my CheckBoxList with values from my database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

How do I set the `CheckBoxList` values with my values stored in my database? 
I have tried using a `datareader` but it doesn't work and I don't know why.

My Code:

```
cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT [SeatID], [Flag] FROM [SeatingPlan] WHERE ([SectionID] = 1 )", con);
dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        if (dr.GetString(1).Equals("true"))
        {
            chkBoxDaysList.Items[i].Selected = true;
            chkBoxDaysList.Items[i].Enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you opening your connection object "con.Open();" ?

Comment: Define "it doesn't work". I saw a suspicious loop inside the while loop.

Comment: it doesn't set the values to the checkbox list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use data adapter instead of using data reader.

and bind it like this.

```
chkBoxDaysList.DataSource = tempds.Tables(0)
chkBoxDaysList.DataTextField = "SeatID"
chkBoxDaysList.DataValueField = "Flag"
chkBoxDaysList.DataBind()
```

Comment: Hi! I use the data adapter and it works well. Thank you for your answer. But I still don't know how to pre-select the checkbox according to the values from the database. I mean if the field Flag is "true", select the checkbox on pageload.

Comment: {
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 const string sqlstr = "SELECT [SeatID], [Flag] FROM [SeatingPlan] WHERE ([SectionID] = 1 )";
 SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlstr, _con_Master);
 da.Fill(ds);
 chkBoxDaysList.DataValueField = "SeatID";
 chkBoxDaysList.DataTextField = "SeatID";
 chkBoxDaysList.DataSource = ds.Tables(0);
 chkBoxDaysList.DataBind();
 Int32 i = 0;
 foreach (DataRow rw in ds.Tables(0).Rows) {
  if (rw.Item(1).ToString().Trim() == "true") {
   chkBoxDaysList.Items(i).Selected = true;
   chkBoxDaysList.Items(i).Enabled = false;
  }
  i = i + 1;
 }
}